# Is there a way to perform multiple lookups across different columns in two tables in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table 1 as below (Simplified versions show here as the actual one has over 60+ columns)

| ID | Description | From_Index_Code | To_Index_Code | Cost | PARAM1 | PARAM2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Something. | A001 | B001 | 500 | abc. | xyz. |
| B | Something2. | B001. | C001 | 1000 | abc. | xyz. |

I have a master table that is of the following structure:

| ID | Code. | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A001. | 100. |
| 2 | B001. | 200. |
| 3 | C001. | 300. |

Now I have an input that has the following values:
PARAM1=abc,PARAM2=xyz and Index value as 150. I need to check if the index value is between A001 and B001, if yes, return 500. If it is between B001 and C001 then I return 1000.

I tried doing

```
WITH
src_1 as (select id,s.description,g.value
from table1 s left outer join table 2 g on s.from_index_code=g.code),
src_2 as (select id,s.description,g.value
from table1 s left outer join table 2 g on s.to_index_code=g.code)
select src_1.id, src_1.description,src_1.value as 'from_value',src_2.value as 'to_value' from src_1 ,src_2 where src_1.id=src_2.id.
```

I expect the resulting set to be something like:

| ID | Description | From_Value | To_Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Something. | 100. | 200. |
| B | Somethng2. | 200. | 300. |

It should have the same number of rows as Table 1. But the resulting output has far too many rows.

Table 1 has 8497 rows.Table 2 has 121 rows. However the resulting output has over 14 million rows.

What is the best way to accomplish this?
Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: 60+ columns? What could be the reason to have so many columns? Are all those columns populated with data? By the way, if that's the exact query you're running, I'll be surprised if it return any results. There are two erroneous parts there, one is the `table 2` name, it has a space in between and the other would be the the `id` column in `select id ..`; both tables that you've joined have column named `id`, therefore it will return an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem was, that you select id in the subselect and so mysql chooses wrong, adding a s to the ids columns clears everything up and gets the correct result

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1
>     (`id` varchar(1), `Description` varchar(11), `From_Index_Code` varchar(5), `To_Index_Code` varchar(4), `Cost` int, `PARAM1` varchar(4), `PARAM2` varchar(4))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO table1
>     (`id`, `Description`, `From_Index_Code`, `To_Index_Code`, `Cost`, `PARAM1`, `PARAM2`)
> VALUES
>     ('A', 'Something.', 'A001', 'B001', 500, 'abc.', 'xyz.'),
>     ('B', 'Something2.', 'B001.', 'C001', 1000, 'abc.', 'xyz.')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table2
>     (`id` int, `Code` varchar(4), `Value` int)
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO table2
>     (`id`, `Code`, `Value`)
> VALUES
>     (1, 'A001', 100.),
>     (2, 'B001', 200.),
>     (3, 'C001', 300.)
> ;
> ```

> ```
> WITH
> src_1 as (select s.id,s.description,g.value
> from table1 s left outer join table2 g on s.from_index_code=g.code),
> src_2 as (select s.id,s.description,g.value
> from table1 s left outer join table2 g on s.to_index_code=g.code)
> select src_1.id, src_1.description,src_1.value as 'from_value',src_2.value as 'to_value' from src_1 ,src_2 where src_1.id=src_2.id
> ```

> ```
> id | description | from_value | to_value
> :- | :---------- | ---------: | -------:
> A  | Something.  |        100 |      200
> B  | Something2. |       null |      300
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=87335fa49868f5a5f3b7a6e96d21e355)*

Comment: Thanks. That was the issue

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . I am thinking you want joins and conditions like this:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2f
     on t2f.code = t1.From_Index_Code join
     table2 t2t
     on t2t.code = t1.to_index_code
where t1.param1 = @param1 and t2.param2 = @param2 and 
      @index_value between t2f.value and t2t.value;
```

For performance, you would want indexes on `table1(param1, param2, from_index_code, to_index_code)` and on `table2(code)` (if it is not already the primary key).